# omitting %0D from a given input while loading a list of urls

Tags: bash

I have this `bash` script which loads a list of `urls` and download each file with a numeric name :

```
counter=1
while IFS= read -r url;do
    fileName="$counter" # Add a rule to define a new name for each file here
    counter=$((counter+1))
    wget -O "$fileName.mp4" "$url"
done < list
```

However when I load `urls` there's a problem, when I open the `urls` in `nano` it looks like this :

```
www.somesite.com/43c264c5a93459842e6bf1cbbc3a1a9b.mp4
www.somesite.com/fa6463dfecb3d03dade573b28531c692.mp4
www.somesite.com/7abac8e804c2a21379b3542d02c871fd.mp4
www.somesite.com/6346cd728b281297eb075804626cf007.mp4
```

However when the `script` loads these `urls` in `$filename` variable it ends up like this :

```
www.somesite.com/24ebbbc4a45a7331e0789fda099f3d55.mp4%0D
```

And that little `%0D` is totally ruining the whole process, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Your script has DOS line endings (CR/LF). Save it using Unix line endings (LF) instead.

Comment: Seems reasonable. However this list was given to me by another person, is there a manual way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those strange characters at the end of your urls are carriage returns.  This could be a sign that that file was created in Windows, where the line endings include a carriage return, followed by a linefeed.  UNIX utilities usually expect lines to end with just a linefeed.

If you're on a machine with the `vim` editor, you can convert the line-endings in the file, `list`, to the UNIX convention by running:

`vim list '+set ff=unix' +wq`

If you would like to automatically remove the carriage return characters from `list` as part of your script, consider something like:

```
counter=1
while read url; do
  wget -O "$counter.mp4" "$url"
  counter=$((counter+1))
done <<<"$(sed 's/\r$//' < list)"
```

Note that this requires GNU sed, with is included with most Linux distributions, and can be installed on OSX using `brew install gnu-sed`.

Comment: No problems.  Just fyi, I edited the solution to add a way to filter the carriage returns out the input automatically, @HassanAbdul-Kareem